# Android: Access fragment TextView from Activity

Tags: android, fragment

I want to access fragment TextView inside my activity because I need to change it from activity. However it returns nullpointerexception. If I put fragment textview inside reference of spinner onItemSelected listener it works. Here is a bit of code to explain. This one works

```
 spinnerOblasti.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                TextView[] vystrahy = new TextView[1];
                vystrahy[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVystrahy);

                vystrahyListener = new htmlParserListener(vystrahy);
                (new htmlParser(0, vystrahyListener) ).execute();

                TextView[] podmienky = new TextView[6];
                podmienky[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPodmienkySkala);
                podmienky[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPodmienkyLad);
                podmienky[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPodmienkyMix);
                podmienky[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPodmienkyLyze);
                podmienky[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPodmienkyTuristika);
                podmienky[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPodmienkyKomentar);

                podmienkyListener = new htmlParserListener(podmienky);
                (new htmlParser(1, podmienkyListener) ).execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

But I need it to work also outside onItemSelected listener. So is there a way to access fragment TextView from Activitiy?

Thanks in forward

Comment: did you try static textview? is it good?

Comment: Create a getter method in your fragment, and call it using fragment's instance from your activity.

Comment: Please include an example of where it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using **Framgnet Callbacks** as described in here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html I believe that this is the best was to pass fragment TextViews into my activity after they are created.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Seshu Vinay
Create a getter in fragment.

```
public String getEditText()
{
    String strEditText = mEditText.getText().toString();
    return strEditText;
}
```

And then call this getter from activity.

```
fragment.getEditText();
```